# vml email code for curved only the one side of the frame

Tags: html-email, vml

I'm working on a custom email template:

```
    <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://google.com" style="height:225px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:600px;" arcsize="45%,0,0,45%" strokecolor="#fffefe" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="frame" src="https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/childrenkids-playground-swing-slide-climbing-260nw-1930215425.jpg" color="#F8F7F1" />
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">.</center>
  </v:roundrect>
```

I'm trying to curve only the left side but instead, it is curving all the corners, is it even possible to curve only the left side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `RoundRect` element can only apply the same curve to all sides. What you can use instead is a `Shape` element with a custom `Path` element.

Here's what it would look like in your example:

```
<v:shape xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" style="height:225px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:600px;" fill="true" stroke="true" strokecolor="#fffefe" coordorigin="0 0" coordsize="600 225">
    <v:fill type="frame" src="https://i.imgur.com/PkQE6Em.png" color="#F8F7F1" />
    <v:path v="m 45,0 l 600,0 l 600,225 l 45,225 qx 0,180 l 0,45 qy 45,0 x" />
</v:shape>
```

In this example, I'm setting a 45px rounded corner on the top left and bottom left. In order to do this, I first defined the `coordsize` attribute to be the same size of the VML shape. This will make it easier to then define the actual path of the shape in the `v` attribute.

Here's how the values in this `v` attribute work:

- `m 45,0`: Start drawing a shape at the point `45,0`.
- `l 600,0`: Draw a line to the point `600,0` (the top right corner).
- `l 600,225`: Draw a line to the point `600,225` (the bottom right corner).
- `l 45,225`: Draw a line to the point `45,225` (just before the start of the bottom left rounded corner).
- `qx 0,180`: Draw the bottom left arc to the point `0,180`.
- `l 0,45`: Draw a straight line up to the point `0,45`.
- `qy 45,0`: Draw the top left arc to the point `0,45`.
- `x`: Close the shape.

If you want to adjust the radius, you can change the `45` values into what you want and the `180` values into the difference between the height of the shape and your radius. (Here it’s `225 - 45`.)